# Swap constraints of one UIView to another UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have an app with certain number of `UIViews`. I now need to swap their positions horizontally. For example, there is a `UIView` called **X** at the left end and one called **Y** at the right end. At a button click, I want **Y** to reside where **X** resided and **X** to come to `UIView` **Y**'s initial position. I figure, I must be able to do this by swapping the `NSLayoutConstraints` of them both(just a guess). But I can't get this to work. Is this idea possible? What will be the `objective-C` code for this?

[image: Original Image]

[image: Swapped Image]

These are the results I got after trying out the first code(almost there, but not completely). I have only applied it to the views **KWI** and **DXB**. What I want is a blind swap between **KWI** and **DXB**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the views are of the same size, then it is not much of a problem. Assume your two views X and Y are called xView and yView. You could do something like this:

```
CGRect xViewFrame = xView.frame;
UIViewAutoresizing xViewResizingConstraints = xView.autoresizingMask;
xView.frame = yView.frame;
xView.autoresizingMask = yView.autoresizingMask;
yView.frame = xViewFrame;
yView.autoresizingMask = xViewResizingConstraints;
```

If you want this animated, you can put it inside a `[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:^{}]` block, and it should work. (I haven't tested it out though)

You could also change the `CGRect xViewFrame` to use `CGPoint xViewCenter` and swap the centers for same-sized views.

The property `autoresizingMask` tells the program what to do in the case of a screen resize - whether by a change in orientation, or a result of device screen size or any other reason.

If the views are NOT of the same size, you would have to deal with the proper margins of your views, and ensure that they do not get clipped outside the screen.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

It seems that you are using UILabels either as your view, or a subview of the two views. If this is the case, make sure you also swap the NSTextAlignment of the UILabels. Something like this:

```
NSTextAlignment xTextAlignment = xView.titleLabel.textAlignment;
xView.titleLabel.textAlignment = yView.titleLabel.textAlignment;
yView.titleLabel.textAlignment = xTextAlignment;
```

Comment: Please see the images I uploaded

Comment: I couldnt get swapping Alignments to work. i simply hardcoded and changed the alignments when swapping began